# Algorithm for computing a score for move and time based game

Tags: java, android

I am creating a puzzle game that consists of moves and time.

Obviously the more moves you end the game with would mean you did better or a level than with a low amount of moves left upon completion.

The time counts from 0 and goes until the player completes the level. The less time it takes the player to complete the level this would mean he/she has done better than using a lot of time to complete the level.

So with this being said, what would be the best way to calculate the players final score to equal a score over 1000 using this information.

P.S I know for some of you this may be easy task, but i would just like some guidance on this.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What paddy said. On another note, you could go

```
(1/sqrt(time) + 2/(moves^2))*1000
```

This at least makes sure that both time used and moves made are inversely proportionate to the amount of point the player gets. moves with this formula count 4 powers as much as time, which is probably overkill.

Comment: I like the formula. What would sqrt be in this case?

Comment: square root. seconds are gonna be in the range of 10-150 i expect so that would degrade the points pretty rapidly. moves^2 probably is overkill though.

Comment: well the seconds in my case start from 0 and count up. So would the code need to change in this case?

Comment: yeah but i dont expect the puzzles are gonna be solved in less than 10 seconds, will they?

Comment: In some cases yes. It just depends on the complexity of the levels. If you new the background of the game you would understand why then. In most cases i doubt it but i still want to be prepared for if someone does.

Comment: Well the root doesnt really hurt with that since x - sqrt(x) becomes larger as x becomes larger, meaning the difference between having the root and not having it is negligible for smaller numbers. so if the player is faster, the root will have less effect on his score than if he takes longer (in which case it will somewhat dampen the degradation of the score).

Comment: When using double finalScore = (1 / Math.sqrt(countDown) + 2 / (moves ^ 2)) * 1000; i get divide by zero exception

Comment: Then either countDown or moves is zero, cant have that; btw i would actually recommend not doing the ^2 since that will give pretty quick degradation of points. Also, change the 1000 to a 500 and the 2 to a 1 because otherwise youre gonna get outside the limit of 1000 points max.

Comment: Im still getting the divide by zero error. I checked and time neither moves are 0

Answer (score 1):

This is so subjective.  Why don't you decide what is appropriate?

You need to decide which is more important: Number of moves, or speed.

Then, work out a suitable penalty for one or the other, and a score multiplier that puts your scores in a reasonable range.

Personally, I'd provide the raw stats sorted by moves first, and time second.  For example:

```
Moves       Time
10          02:30
15          02:00
15          02:35
20          01:50
```

Here I've used number of moves *used*, rather than *remaining*.  Your description was confusing.

Comment: I agree! Thanks for bringing that to my attention. The thing is each level has a certain amount of moves based upon how the level is set up or the difficulty. So i could still use your approach. But for example if a user has 4 moves for a level and uses 2 of those moves and completes the level in 10 seconds. How would you recommend computing a score in that format?

Comment: Either have a different set of rankings for each difficulty level, or do something like *"percentage of total moves used multiplied by time taken"* and make it so a lower score is desirable.